# Swapping columns in R returns 'subscript out of bounds'

Tags: r, swap

The following bit of code should swap columns between levels of an array, but it results in a 'subscript out of bounds' error:

```
pop <- array(1:25, dim = c(5, 10, 2)) # 2-level array with 5 rows and 10 columns
m <- 0.20 # proportion of columns to swap
K <- 2    

inds1 <- sample(ncol(pp), size = ceiling(ncol(x) * m), replace = FALSE) # sample random columns 
inds2 <- sample(ncol(pop), size = ceiling(ncol(x) * m), replace = FALSE)

    for (i in 1:K) { # swap columns between subarrays
      for(j in 1:K) {
        tmp <- pop[i,, inds1]
        pop[i,, inds1] <- pop[j,, inds2]
        pop[j,, inds2] <- tmp
    }
  }

Error in pop[i, , inds1] : subscript out of bounds
```

I wondering why R throws an error here. It should also work for any n-level array. Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Where is `K` defined?

Comment: is `x` supposed to be `pop`?

Comment: I've now defined K - sorry about that

Comment: @MelissaKey yes, you are correct. This has been fixed in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the way `x` is defined, the subsets are:

```
x[row, column, array level]
```

You are trying to access the columns in the array level spot. So if you had for example `inds1 = 3` then `pop[i, ,inds1]` would be trying to access the third array which doesn't exist. See below for a working example. To address your current example we need more info on `pop` and `K`:

```
x <- array(1:25, dim = c(5, 10, 2)) # 2-level array with 5 rows and 10 columns
m <- 0.20 # proportion of columns to swap    

set.seed(1)
inds1 <- sample(ncol(x), size = ceiling(ncol(x) * m), replace = FALSE) # sample random columns 
inds2 <- sample(ncol(x), size = ceiling(ncol(x) * m), replace = FALSE)

x
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    6   11   16   21    1    6   11   16    21
#[2,]    2    7   12   17   22    2    7   12   17    22
#[3,]    3    8   13   18   23    3    8   13   18    23
#[4,]    4    9   14   19   24    4    9   14   19    24
#[5,]    5   10   15   20   25    5   10   15   20    25
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    6   11   16   21    1    6   11   16    21
#[2,]    2    7   12   17   22    2    7   12   17    22
#[3,]    3    8   13   18   23    3    8   13   18    23
#[4,]    4    9   14   19   24    4    9   14   19    24
#[5,]    5   10   15   20   25    5   10   15   20    25

inds1;inds2
[1] 3 4
[1] 6 9
```

So to swap column 3 & 6 and column 4 & 9 we can do:

```
temp <- x[, inds1, 1]
x[,inds1, 1] <- x[,inds2, 2]
x[,inds2, 2] <- temp
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this implementation. 'x' is supposed to be 'pop' -- my mistake. K is just the number of levels of the array